# Geometric Interpretation of Product of Two Multivariate Gaussians densities

Tags: normal-distribution, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, estimation, density-function

I am trying to understand the high-dimensional geometry behind Bayesian estimation.

When you multiply two Normal densities with respective means $\mu_1, \mu_2$ and covariances $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$, the renormalized product is again a Normal density $\mathcal N (\mu_3, \Sigma_3)$, as is shown in this post: [Product of Two Multivariate Gaussians Distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157172/product-of-two-multivariate-gaussians-distributions), in summary:
\begin{align}
\Sigma_3 &=(\Sigma_1^{-1}+\Sigma_2^{-1})^{-1}\\
&= \Sigma_1(\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2)^{-1}\Sigma_2\\
\mu_3 &= \Sigma_2(\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2)^{-1}\mu_1 + \Sigma_1(\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2)^{-1}\mu_2\\
&=\Sigma_3(\Sigma_1^{-1}\mu_1 + \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2)
\end{align}

The formulas are clear, and the intuition of what happens, too:

- The new precision (inverse covariance) is the sum of the old precisions.
- The new mean is a weighted average of the old means.

**The thing I cannot grasp is the geometric interpretation of the multivariate weighted average.**
In 1D, and in general if the eigenvectors of the covariance matrices are collinear, then $\mu_3$ is on the line between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, i.e. $\mu_3 = \alpha\mu_1 + (1-\alpha)\mu_2$, where $\alpha \equiv \alpha(\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2)\in[0,1]$. But what if the eigenvectors are not collinear?

The intuition is that it goes where the contour ellipsoids "overlap". (Sorry, not enough reputation for visualizations, but this [blog on Kalman filters](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/) does a pretty good job.)
But where exactly is that point? 
Here is what I found:

- It's not intersection of the lines defined by the eigenvectors.
- The second equation for the mean suggests: transfer them into the coordinate system defined by their respective covariance. Add them, then skew the result with the new covariance. I do not really understand what this means geometrically.
- I found that this last point is related to the canonical form of the Normal distribution, in that $\Sigma_i^{-1}\mu_i$ is one of the canonical parameters. But I don't have an interpretation for adding these, let alone multiplying them with the new covariance.
- I could not pin down this concept of "overlapping ellipsoids". Which ellipsoids? Is it an intersection? The mass point of an intersection area? Something completely different?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Sad to see this question goes unanswered...