# Multivariate Gaussian product derivation

Tags: normal-distribution

I see from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157172/product-of-two-multivariate-gaussians-distributions) that the product of two multivariate Gaussians is $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where:

$\mu = \Sigma_2(\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2)^{-1}\mu_1 +\Sigma_1(\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2)^{-1}\mu_2$

$\Sigma =(\Sigma_1^{-1}+\Sigma_2^{-1})^{-1}$

I've also seen the following result,

$(\Sigma_1^{-1}+\Sigma_2^{-1})^{-1}= \Sigma_1-\Sigma_1(\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2)^{-1}\Sigma_1.$

My question is how is this result derived?