# How to derive this for product of gaussians

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I have a $D$ dimensional distribution $q$ which can be written as proportional to the following-

$q(z) \propto \prod_{i=1}^D \mathcal{N} \big(z_{i}| \eta_i, \lambda_i^{-1} \big) \times \mathcal{N}(z| \mu, \Sigma)$

where the $\eta_i$ and $\lambda_i^{-1}$ are depend on $i$. Notation: $\lambda_i^{-1}$ is the variance.

How should I simplify this? I know that a product of Gaussians will be a Gaussian hence the proportionality constant will go away since the result can be normalized.

I tried the following -

$$
\begin{align}
    \ln q&(z) = \sum_{i=1}^D \ln \mathcal{N} \big(z_{i}| \mu_i, \lambda_i^{-1} \big) + \ln  \mathcal{N}(z| \mu, \Sigma) + \text{const}   \\
    &= - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^D \lambda_i \big(z_{i} - \mu_i \big)^2 - \frac{1}{2} (z -\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (z-\mu) + \text{const}   \,. \nonumber
\end{align}
$$

but I don't know how to proceed further. Can someone please help me derive a concise expression for the distribution $q(z)$ which is simply just a Multivariate Gaussian?

Comment: "The product of Gaussians will be a Gaussian". Do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Here is one reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157172/product-of-two-multivariate-gaussians-distributions